# What do i need to create single page website like this?

Tags: javascript, html

I found this website and impressed on it https://kvellhome.com/

what technology do I need if I want to create a website like that

- Is it Ajax? (I tried to remove some article but it can reload itself when I changed article back)
- HTML5 history (I found that it can reach by direct link)

Comment: Try this url to get an idea : view-source:https://kvellhome.com/

Comment: I tried but I can't found any framework except jQuery. I wondered what technology that they use when they want to change article to any article.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think this can guide you to the right direction.

1- the homepage is a simple landing page that usese some animations to change colors and display text.

2 - when clicking on discover, it slides on the right and initialize a second slider that uses the projects's name as navigation dots ([can easily be done using css pseudo elements using data attribute as content](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/05/using-custom-data-attributes-and-pseudo-elements/))

3 - you click on the project itself and it load a parallax page for that specific project.

Menu | contacts | about are pretty simple, they are pages on their own.

Some libraries you could possibly use:

[fullscreenjs](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) (to create the fullscreen pages and sliders. the home page can be the first slider and then on the second page you initialize a slider inside a slider (so that the animation to the right looks like the one  on the website you provided)

[animatecss](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to animate stuff

[parallax](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) for all the parallax effects

I think this is personal preference, but if I had to do a website like that, I will tackle it this way. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a few question how they change to each page? Is it ajax? such as when we visit this link [https://kvellhome.com/catalog/kaptain](https://kvellhome.com/catalog/kaptain) then we click on back button that it is at top right of the page.

Comment: If you use the fullpagejs slider, the URL changes according to each slide you are currently viewing. It appends the slider id as #{sliderID}, and with this method it's easy to just use history.goBack(-1) in javascript to go back to the previous URL, which is also the last one you were on before changing page.